# can not run command npm run deploy?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! robofriends@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the robofriends@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hardik Sachan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-29T16_31_31_944Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What is your `deploy` script?

Comment: deploy: `gh-pages -d build`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I couldn't figure out what the problem was because I was able to push to my repo the entire time but could not get gh-pages to build my page.  I fixed it by changing the following -

In my terminal, I typed:

> git remote set-url origin *https://github.com/username/projectname.git*

what was in there before was my password protected SSH key.  I went to my repo, clicked the 'code' button and copied the link for my https and inputted it where the italic text is above.  I ran 'npm run deploy', it prompted me to login through my browser again but after that, it finally worked.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I have solved this issue using these commands:  
eval `ssh-agent -s ` 
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519